# win iot Promises, UWP nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, uwp, es6-promise, windowsiot

I'm developing some Tests for an win iot with nodejs-server.
Basically that works really good.

I'm using the uwp-namespace to talk to an raspberry pi like

```
var uwp = require("uwp");
uwp.projectNamespace("Windows");
...
```

see: (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldnode)

Many of these uwp-methods returning an WinJS.Promise (which works also great).
But when I'm trying to create my own Promise

like

```
var p = new Promise(resolve=>{
   // do something
    resolve("ok");
})

p.then(x=>{
    alert("yeah, its ok");
})
```

it just won't call the "then"-listener.
I followed several easy tutorials for creating promises in typescript wihtout success. (When I listen to the Winjs-Promises it always works)

any ideas how to create an WinJS-Promise?

***UPDATE***:

It seems that it only doesn't work when I try to create an promise inside an WinJS.Promise-Callback like

```
myWinJsPromise.then(x => {
    var p = new Promise(...)...
})
```

***UPDATE2***:

to make this clearer I will post some more code:

```
export class MyClass
{
    private _myobject:any=null;

    public GetMyObjectAsync(): Promise<any>
    {
        if(this._myobject)
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this._myobject));

        return CallSomeUwpMethodAsync().then(x => {
            this.myobject = x
            return x; //WinJs-Promise get resolved after returning something.
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, it works fine for me. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ek1d56c/).

Comment: I think you'll have to expand a bit more. What isn't working? And there is no need to create a new promise inside the `.then()` (this is an anti-pattern) since it's already returning a promise. You can simply return/resolve whatever inside the `.then()` and it will be wrapped in the existing promise.

Comment: I only need the "new Promise" to wrap an existing object because the method returns an promise if the object doesn't exit. See my Update2 above.

Comment: I don't think that made it more clear. In the first part `myWinJsPromise.then( x => { var p = new Promise(...) })` the `new Promise(..)` doesn't make sense. From *where* does `myWinJsPromise` come?

Comment: Update 2 is more clear. this is what I want to achive. and in this case "new Promise" is not working...